# How do you send a Push Notification to an IOS device from an OSX app? I am getting error 107

Tags: ios, macos, parse-platform

I am writing an OSX program than manages a membership database. One of the features is to be able to send messages to members who have installed the companion app.

I've recently learned that push notifications using the parse SDK can only be done on IOS devices, and to do so from a Mac, I would have to use the restful api. No Prob. But I am having a problem,.

I have method :

```
-(void)sendPushNotification:(NSString*)strTheDeviceToken TheMessage:(NSString*) strTheMessage{
    //POST
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/push"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"where\":{"];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"deviceToken\":\""]];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:strTheDeviceToken];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"},\"data\":{"]];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"alert\": \""]];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:strTheMessage];
    post = [post stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"}}"]];
    NSLog(@"The JSON post = '%@'",post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"MyAPIdHere" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [request setValue:@"MyRestKeyHere" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];

    NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
    NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
    NSLog(@"DONE!");
}
```

The JSON that is sent looks correctly formed :

```
{
    "where": {
        "deviceToken": "-tokenhere-"
    },
    "data": {
        "alert": "This is a test"
    }
}
```

But the result back is :

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid json: "}
```

Can someone see where I've gone wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never fails - as soon as you post - you find your own mistake.
Forgot the critical line :

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

DOH!